# Pocketing queen when not allowed

Tags: carrom

What happens if you hit the queen in when you're not supposed to?

Answer (score 2):

From [The Laws of Carrom](https://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm):

> 95) a) If the Queen is pocketed before any C/m of the player is
>   pocketed, the Queen shall be taken out for placing and the player
>   shall lose his turn.
>
> b) If a player pockets the Queen, while there is a Due against him,
>   the Queen shall be taken out for placing and the player shall lose his
>   turn.
>
> c) However, if after recovery of Due and/or penalty, all the nine C/m
>   are on the C/B, a player shall have the right to pocket the Queen and
>   to cover it.
>
> d) If, at the break or in a subsequent stroke when all his nine C/m
>   are on the C/B, the Queen is pocketed along with the Striker, the
>   Queen shall be taken out for placing and a Due shall be declared. The
>   player shall lose his turn.